# the parameter is incorrect shortcut create VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a shortcut and I have a problem with this piece of code

```
      Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

        If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            Dim str As String = """--start-time=60"

            TargetName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName & str
            ' MyShortcut = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(MyPath)

         End If
```

receive the following error: `the parameter is incorrect (exception from hResult) 0x80070057 ((E invalid arg)))`

all I want is to create this piece of code using the shortcut and look exactly like this on the target:

or please, using my directory path to do so for the executable I choose.

```
"C:\Program Files\MySoftware\Studio\executable.exe" --start-time=120
```

unfortunately if I only use `TargetName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName`

This shortcut will create for me: with the code above which is more precisely a function.

```
"C:\Program Files\MySoftware\Studio\executable.exe--start-time=120
```

and if I put `TargetName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName & str` it shows me the above error.

```
`the parameter is incorrect (exception from hResult) 0x80070057 ((E invalid arg)))`
```

So how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be putting an extra quotation mark in when you want a space;

Try this:

```
 Dim str As String = " --start-time=60"
 TargetName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName & str
```

or if you need quotation marks around the exe, try this:

```
 Dim str As String = """ --start-time=60"
 TargetName = """" & OpenFileDialog1.FileName & str
```

Comment: thank you very much, I will try, I hope it works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70652445/modify-my-target-the-parameter-is-incorrect-in-vb-net